# optimizing performance for insert_many() and create_index in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, pymongo

I am new to mongo and pymongo and I have a large amount of data about 5 million documents to insert I am using ijson to read in the data from the JSON file and storing it that only takes the program a few seconds to do
the code looks like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017,w=0)
db = client['emp']
emp_colelction = db['EmpDetails']
.
.(skip over reading in data from the JSON file)
.
emp_data = [
      {
        "EmpId": "1",
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Builder",
        "EmpType": "FullTime",
        "HireDate": "2010-08-17"
        "Hobbys":["baseball", "Basketball", "Netflix", "writing", "Programing"]
       },
       {
        "EmpId": "2",
        "FirstName": "Peter",
        "LastName": "Griffin",
        "EmpType": "PartTime",
        "HireDate": "2019-05-23"
        "Hobbys":["vollyball", "Basketball", "Hulu", "Reading", "Learning"]
       }
]

track_insert_time = time.time()

emp_colelction.insert_many(emp_data, ordered=False) 

print("Insertion time: %s"%(time.time()-track_insert_time))

track_index_time = time.time()

emp_collection.create_index(["EmpId", 1])  
  
print("Create index time: %s"%(time.time()-track_index_time)
```

the field "hobbys" can be a list of an arbitrary number of elements some are upwards of 300 elements.

I am just using the community edition of MongoDB on my Macbook pro 13 inch 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
the times on my computer are the following:
Insertion time: ~90 seconds
Create index time: ~110 seconds

it seems like the insertion is very slow because python inserts one document and waits for a response from MongoDB before inserting the next one. I am still a noob in python to write a multithreading program.

any ideas?
I was thinking maybe I insert chunks of data at a time instead of trying to insert everything all at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertions via [bulk writes](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html) (which you appear to already be using) should be quite efficient.

Review CPU and disk use on the server - if the server has available CPU but the client is CPU-limited, using multiple clients would increase throughput. This is unlikely to be the case for simple inserts though.

One caveat with bulk writes is the driver automatically splits them to fit into the server limits (16 MB documents, 48 MB command messages). If you are trying to bulk write truly large arrays you may get better performance if you insert 1000 or 5000 documents at a time.